# Replacing laptop battery affects OS loading

Tags: boot, laptop, windows-8.1, battery

I have a one and a half year old laptop with a win8.1 OS. On it first year, it prompt me that the battery is damaged and should be replaced. So I brought my laptop, along with its battery, to a computer hardware store and have it changed. We bought a replacement battery, different model (my model is not available), but with the same color, shape, number of pin and fits perfectly. The technician told us that even it is a different model, its fine, so we tested it and went home. When we returned home, **something happened**. My laptop tries to load the OS (the blue Windows 8 logo) and turns black and restarts! Over and over again! I tried afterwards to run the laptop without the new battery but the fault still exists. I reuse the old damaged battery to my laptop, thinking that its the new battery's fault why it happened, but it still restarts!

On my process of self-pitying, I've red the writings on the old battery's. It has this text: *"If the same model is not found, please use this other compatible models: blah, blah, blah, etc."*. And the new battery model was not there.

I'm using my laptop in safe mode until this day (Yep, no problem in safe mode). My question is, **does changing battery can affect the OS?**

P.S. I've tried to reformat my harddisk and install a fresh OS: Windows and Linux (thinking the fault will go away), but the fault also occurred when booting from the CD-ROM / USB drive, thus I cannot proceed on reformatting...

Comment: Was anything else at all changed while replacing the battery? Did the store employee even turn the laptop on, play with anything, take apart anything besides just removing the battery? Does not sounds like just a battery problem... Are all your BIOS settings still the same? Maybe hard drive is in the wrong mode or something, preventing normal booting?

Comment: @Xen2050 On the hardware side: The technician put the new battery, only that, On the software side: He turned it on and go to the bios, changed the date and time, save changes load the windows and run, on the screen where you supposed to pick a user, he then choose to shutdown... So I thought everything worked well....

Comment: Hmmm, if it booted OK at the store, but not at home, it's a little mysterious. Unless the battery could have completely died & erased all the BIOS settings in between the store & home... I think some laptops have a separate BIOS battery, like desktops, but that's my only idea for now. Or, tried going back to the store as soon as you found out it wasn't working? Within a few hours, or a day or two preferably?

Comment: @Xen2050 I returned, but the technician got relieved and replaced (_how ironic!_) by someone else. The new technician told me its not their fault because it worked fine before we left the store... Its infuriating and I've never set foot on their store again. On the side-note, I tried to search for my laptop's infrastructure, and indeed, its motherboards has its own battery to save bios setting, totally independent with the laptop's battery. And every restart I check the BIOS, the setting is indeed saved- not changed.

Comment: That is upsetting. I suppose it is theoretically possible that the new battery could have done something to damage something in your laptop, preventing a normal bootup... **Unless anyone else has any ideas** on settings to try changing in BIOS (could experiment yourself, write down changes) it may be time to backup all your important data & start looking into the manufacturer's warranty for the laptop (or later battery). And if you don't want to have the laptop manufacturer immediately say NO, you may want to not mention the new battery, since it doesn't work properly with the old battery now.

Comment: @Xen2050 Thanks... I already backed up my data to a separate laptop. And... yeah... I'm experimenting the hardware a bit (I got a little knowledge, I'm a programmer by the way), noting details along the way. I'm already attached to this problem, **I want to solve this problem this badly**, partially because the warranty had already ended. :-(

Comment: Does it boot without the battery when you have it plugged in?

Comment: @DeanSpicer, ever since I put the new battery, it restarts, regardless if I run it without any battery, run using the old battery, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the computer exhibits the same fault with or without the battery in - and when running off mains power, it is most likely coincidental - Maybe you knocked the hard computer when you were returned home from where you got the new battery and damaged something.

There is a very, very, very slim possibility there is some DRM in the battery which is causing you issues - what is the make and model of your laptop ?

You should also check the voltages the new battery is capable of providing and confirm that it is the same as the old one.   This is unlikely to be the issue, but it is conceivable.

Also, you say the "Blue logo" - can you advise if this is the Windows logo or something else ?

Another thing you may want to try is getting a Linux distro and seeing if you can run it off a USB key.  If you can do this you can start running hardware tests and isolate the problem.

Comment: I cannot boot from USB nor via CD-ROM, it always restarts. Suppose something _has been_ damaged while we return home, I cant see why safe mode is running?

Comment: And the old and the new battery, and as well as the laptop were all made by the same manufacturer: Acer